# Find curve satisfying conditions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Given a point:

$$  \overline{x} =  (x_1,x_2)$$

And a curve: 
$$ a_1(t) = (a_{11}(t), a_{12}(t)) $$

I am asked to find  the function

$$ a_2(t) = (a_{21}(t), a_{22}(t))$$

Such that:

$$ (a_2(t)-\overline{x})\cdot(a_2(t)-\overline{x})=c_1\tag1$$
$$ (a_2(t)-a_1(t))\cdot(a_2(t)-a_1(t))=c_2\tag2$$

If we define $$F:R^3 \mapsto R,  F(\overline{x},t) = (\overline{x}-a_1(t))\cdot (\overline{x}-a_1(t))\tag3$$
$$ h(t) = (a_{21}(t), a_{22}(t), t) \tag4$$

Since $ F \circ h(t) = c_2 $ using the chain rule:

$$ (a_1(t) \cdot a'_1(t)) + (a_2(t) \cdot a_2'(t))- (a_1'(t)\cdot a_2(t) )- (a'_2(t)\cdot a_1(t)) = 0\tag5$$

From here I suppose that $$ a_1(t) =  (c_1) ^2(sin(k(t)) + x_1, cos(k(t)) + x_2)\tag6$$

And try t solve for $k(t)$. 
I dont have idea how to solve the problem, I need a hint or something because I dont think I am going in the right diretion.

Comment: I took the liberty of numbering your equations so that they could be referred to. Now, for any given $t$ you may just find $a_2(t)$ from (1) and (2). It's pure planimetry, nothing more. You don't need any calculus at all.